# Is possible to change search method in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have csv file with 30 000 lines. I have to select many values based on many conditions, so insted of many loops and "if's" i decided to use linq. I have written class to read csv. It implements IEnumerable to be used with linq. This is my enumerator:

```
class CSVEnumerator : IEnumerator
{

    private CSVReader _csv;

    private int _index;

    public CSVEnumerator(CSVReader csv)
    {
        _csv = csv;
        _index = -1;
    }

    public void Reset(){_index = -1;}


    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            return new CSVRow(_index,_csv);
        }
    }


    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return ++_index < _csv.TotalRows;
    }

}
```

It's working, but it's slow. Let's say i want to select max value in column A in range 100;150 row.

```
max  = (from CSVRow r in csv where r.ID > 100 && r.ID < 150 select r).Max(y=>y["A"]);
```

This will work, but linq searches for max value in 30 000 rows instead of 48.
As I said, I could use loop, but only in this example case, conditions are "brutal" :)

Is there any way to override linq collection search. Something like: look into query used on my enumerator, look, if any linq conditions in "where" contains "row ID filter" and give another data based on this.

I don't want to copy part of data to another array/collection and problem is not in my csv reader. Accessing every row by id is fast, only problem is when you access all 30 000 of them. 
Any help appriciated :-)

Comment: BTW, you should implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: How is this implemented ->  `new CSVRow(_index,_csv)`. Random access or sequential access?

Comment: Are you sure that linq to objects applies Max to all your records and not only these 48? Strange, it should apply operators sequentially. My guess is that your enumerator is just slow.

Comment: Probably the problem is the reader which has no implementation here. Try reading the full file just once and then work with that. Should be fast enough and 30k lines should not consume to much memory.

Comment: Tilak:
It accesses row _index without passing all rows < _index - direct "random" access.

Wiktor: I am sure, I tried breakpoints on MoveNext in Enumerator.

Mare: Already tried, cached on startup, it consumed 60MB - no problem about size(I din't expected that), but same problem :(

Another problem could be in creation of new objects in:  return new CSVRow(_index,_csv);, but it still doesn't solve "brute-force search problem"

Comment: Wiktor: Sorry I misunderstood you question, you are right, max is done only on 48 rows, but to aquire them, it has to search all 30k. Reader accepts access by index, so it's ineffective to search 100 lines if their index is bigger than 100 and other 30k - 150 if their index is lower than 150

Comment: What if you add a .ToList() right before the .Max()?

Comment: Please always specify which flavor of LINQ you're using, and don't just say "LINQ".

Comment: @GiscardBiamby That certainly won't help anything. Why do you think it should?

Comment: @svick I'm used to using LINQ to NHibernate so whatever I thought was probably wrong. I thought it might materialize the results of the "between rows 100 and 150" expression into a list first, and then the `.Max()` would only be applied on that filtered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to be able to use LINQ for this efficiently, you would need to use [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx), in a similar (but much simpler) way than what various LINQ providers for SQL databases do. While doable, I think it would be quite a lot of code for such a simple task.

Because of that, I think a better solution would be to use a separate method to select the rows you want (and then possibly use LINQ to work with the result).

Also, many operations that return collections (including your original code and my modification) can be simplified by using [iterator methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx).

So, your code could look something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<CSVRow> GetRows(
    this CSVReader reader, int idGreaterThan, int idLessThan)
{
    for (int i = idGreaterThan + 1; i < idLessThan; i++)
    {
        yield return new CSVRow(reader, i);
    }
}
```

Here, it's an extension method for `CSVReader`, but another solution (e.g. actual method on that class) might be more appropriate for you.

Your example would then look something like:

```
max = csvReader.GetRows(100, 150).Max(y => y["A"]);
```

(Also, I find it weird that when you have limits 100 and 150, you actually want rows between 101 and 149. But I'm assuming you have a reason for that, so I did the same.)

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you :-)
100 and 150 was only example to show problem, if I post real condition, I would have to explain where does variables come from, which datatypes are etc...

Answer (score 1):

As far as LINQ is concerned, r.ID is simply a value that is being filtered and so all 30k lines are considered for use in the Max operation. If this is a row index, which seems to be the case here, you can use Skip and Take to avoid comparing all 30k rows.

```
max = csv.Skip(100).Take(50).Max(y => y["A"]);
```

Comment: But this will still iterate 150 rows, isntead of 50. So, if the range was 29000-29050, you would iterate 29050 rows, which is very ineffective.

Comment: @svik: How does your CSVReader know in which row he is if you skip the first 29000? You still need to read all of them before so you select the right lines. I guess the CSVReader implementation is inefficient. It should cache the already read lines then nearly all queries will be fast.

Comment: @AloisKraus I have no idea how is `CSVReader` implemented, but the question says that it retrieve any single row efficiently.

Comment: Since a CSV file has no index there is no way to skip lines and keep track how many lines were skipped except if the input format is fixed width or the id column does give you sequential ordering where you can find the matching row via a binary search. I do not think that the implementation is so efficient that the disc read speed would be the limitting factor. But for 30K rows I would simply read it at once and be done with it.

Comment: I agree that the more objects (lines in this case) that are skipped performance degrades. However, I think this would be better addressed in a smarter CSVReader implementation. I believe that this is what @JerKimball is alluding to.

Answer (score 0):

@DougM is right about the order of evaluation, but in this case what I would do is take a one time hit on initialization and generate lookups for any "index" fields: basically, pre calculate a map (dictionary) of row index to row. That said, this would only be useful if you have many repeated queries for a given index field.